# add value just in the first iteration of loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im using the following code and I need to concatenate the key and value but the edit property should be add to the string just in the begining(just in the first time),how should I do that ? I try to find index for the current and the list without success...any idea?

```
string Meassage = null;
foreach (var current in PropList)
{
    Meassage = "edit:" + current.Key + "=" + current.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the list of key-value pairs into `Message` in your loop, and then pre-pend `"edit:"` to it at the end, like this:

```
foreach (var current in PropList) {
    Message += current.Key + "=" + current.Value + " ";
}
Message = "edit:" + Message;
```

Note that this is *not* an efficient way of doing this: rather than appending values to `string`, you could use `StringBuilder` or [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Message = "edit:" + string.Join(" ", PropList.Select(current => current.Key + "=" + current.Value));
```

Comment: You might consider preceding the `Message` with `"edit:"`  only if the `PropList` contains anything, i.e. if the `PropList` is empty, so is the `Message`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Proplist = new Dictionary<int, string>();

Proplist.Add(1, "test1");
Proplist.Add(2, "test2");

var first = Proplist.First();
int key = first.Key;

string Message = null;
foreach (var current in Proplist)
{
    if (first.Key == current.Key)
    {
        //do only one
    }
    else
    {
        Message = "edit:" + current.Key + "=" + current.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add some additional info about your answer? This can help others in the future

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it using LINQ would be to run `Aggregate` on the `PropList` (given that is a collection type that is LINQ-compatible):

```
string message = PropList.Count > 0
  ? PropList.Aggregate("edit:", (agg, current) => agg + current.Key + "=" + current.Value)
  : null;
```

When concerned with performance/memory usage it would also be a good idea to use a `StringBuilder` to decrease the number of memory allocations, but I guess that's not a required thought here.

Just for completeness sake you can do the above using a `StringBuilder` as well, I personally like the conciseness:

```
string message = PropList.Count > 0
  ? PropList.Aggregate(new StringBuilder("edit:"), 
      (builder, current) => builder.Append(current.Key).Append("=").Append(current.Value)).ToString()
  : null;
```